# Open-source, free Java Decompiler

Tags: software-recommendation, java

Is there any open source Java Decompilers for Ubuntu, preferably in the repositories and/or GPL'ed?

Both [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/) and [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/), the most popular decompilers I've found after a bit of googling, seems to be available only in binary form. And they are both proprietary.

It's hard to believe there is *no* such software in Ubuntu (or Linux in general).

If there is more than one, which you recommend, and why?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no **current** open source java decompiler.  JAD is generally the best and is protected by a tweaked version of UPX...so the binary is only minimally obfuscated.  I haven't delved in to completely taking it apart yet, but it seems silly to pack something that takes other things apart...

Comment: Ranking of open source java decompilers: http://aegif-labo.blogspot.jp/2013/03/what-is-best-open-source-java-decompiler.html

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: nice post! :) And good to see that both Krakatau and Procyon, the ones mentioned as answers here, are listed with praise in that blog. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out:

- [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau); the author is active on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420279/antimony).
- [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/)
- [Procyon decompiler](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler)
- [Fernflower](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine) and [mirror](https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower)

Comment: Hum, that's a start. It is GPL v3, hosted on github, very active commit-wise, so 3 major pros... As for cons, it looks like a very young project. Have you ever used it? Have any idea how it compares with, for example, JAD?

Answer (score 8):

- **[mstrobel/procyon's Java Decompiler](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler)**, actively developed

Here's a recent discussion with participation from procyon's author (BonesJustice) and Krakatau's author (Uncaffeinated): http://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/comments/1fb1to/new_open_source_java_decompiler/